# How to "trick" a disabled button? Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox and a button. The button is disabled. You can type text to the textbox and then you can press the button to submit. Actually when the first character is typed from the keyboard the button is enabled.

I tried pasting text in the textbox but this is not enable the button to summit.

```
document.getElementById("Textbox").value="My Text";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("Textbox").innerHTML="My Text";
```

Even if i locate the button it self and activating it wont let me submit unless the text within the textbox was from the keyboard.

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false; // this will enable the button but wont submit
```

I assume that there is a variable that can be changed in order this to happen. But how can i locate this variable?

Comment: Setting `disabled = true` will not enable it. It will disable it. That being said, there is no unique answer to your question. Every website has its own way of checking whether a form can be submitted or not. Some require a `blur` event on a field, some use an `input` event, etc..

Comment: There's probably some type of form validation that's further preventing the submission.

Comment: @blex Yes i agree, my bad. i mean to write false. Also i tried  focus() but did not work. Is there any way to "trick" it like it was from the keyboard?

Comment: @blex To be specific the website is eBay, for ex. sending a message to another user.

Comment: Even if you get the form to submit, there will likely be server-side validation that blocks whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: What is toggling the disabled state of the button? There is no markup nor logic in your question that indicates these. Please create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example instead.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Here is what i tried for that. I loaded the page and then i removed my ethernet cable. The i typed from my keyboard and the button went to enabled. The message that showed up on eBay was "Something went wrong. Please try again.". Then i deleted the message and replaced it with ```value="My Text"; ``` and eBay showed a message that says "Message cannot be empty" and removed my text. So i dont think this is a server side validation

Comment: @Terry Button State changes when the first character is typed into the textbox from the keyboard. By pasting text with ```value="My Text";``` will not enable the button.

Comment: It seems to me that questions about circumventing controls on eBay are not allowed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284463/are-hacking-questions-allowed

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I don't think that sending a "Thank you msg" is like trying to hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried it on the site you mention, and it uses an `input` event. I tried it and it sends the message successfully:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('msg_cnt_cnt'),
    button   = document.getElementById('sndBtn');

// Set the value
textarea.value = "My Text";
// Trigger an input event to enable the button
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: 1, cancelable: 1}));
// Wait 50 milliseconds and click it (it does not work if you don't wait a little)
setTimeout(function() { button.click(); }, 50);
```

Comment: Yes this works. This is what i wanted to do ```textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: 1, cancelable: 1}));``` I broke my brain to find that, you are a legend!

Comment: Glad I could help! Now I hope I won't be reported on eBay for sending 2 useless messages to a seller ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the button, or be sure that the button is not disabled, would suggest to use:

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("Button").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Or provide more parts of the script, maybe there is some event you created which is triggered? Is your Button element id correct?

Comment: ```disabled = false``` does change it from gray to colour but when i try ```document.getElementById("Button").click()``` it wont work

Comment: Well the button is being disabled. Why the form is not being submitted via the DOM click method, this is another issue xD. Have you tried submitting the form? Instead of simulating the click?     document.getElementById("FormId").submit()